# Default namespace of the xsl:document

Tags: variables, xslt

I created originally the following variable:

```
<xsl:variable as="document-node()" name="changesTexts">
            <xsl:document>
                <ps >
                    <p>Processed with <ptr target="#{$applicationID}"/>.</p>
                    <p>proofreading according to workflow 1.1.</p>
                </ps>
            </xsl:document>
</xsl:variable>
```

When I tried to access it like this

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="$changesTexts//p"/>
```

It didn't work: an empty item() was the result.

After I added the namespace to the root element,

```
<ps xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
```

I can access the desired elements by:

```
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="$changesTexts//mei:p"/>
```

So basically I solved my problem but I would like to understand how the things work. I couldn't figure out what kind of default namespace the elements in the first case get. I tried:

- name() (BTW this doesn't show me the namespace in the regular xml document either)
- namespace-uri()

Also, I noticed in the debugger, that the variable $changesTexts is of the type `document-node` and in other cases, when I use `fn:document()`, the variables are of the type document-node(1). So there is obviously some subtle difference (?)

Comment: Have you got a default namespace, of the form `xmlns="..."` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element in your XSLT?

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using your description alone: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW6 There must be something else at work.

Comment: It looks like the `@xpath-default-namespace` causes the problem. However even if I try to match the element with the respective prefix it doesn't match. Here is the updated [test snippet](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW6/2) by @micheal.hor257k.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a literal result element S in XSLT to create an element R in your result tree, the expanded name of R will be the same as the expanded name of S: that is, it will have the same local-name and the same namespace.

So the namespace of the elements constructed by your `<ps>` and `<p>` instructions is determined by the default namespace declared in the stylesheet (probably on the `xsl:stylesheet` element, but it could be on some inner element).